# onfocus and onblur Javascript does not work with Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, action

I have an html file and a javascript file.

I basically have a field that changes the color of an icon when it is focused, but I am unable to change it back to normal when it loses focus. See the image for an idea.

[image]

I have a different set of functions for each field.

See `script.js`

```
function chbgn(color) {
    var background = document.getElementById('iname');
    var icon = document.getElementById('user');
    background.style.backgroundColor = color;
    icon.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
}
function blur() {
    var background = document.getElementById('iname');
    var icon = document.getElementById('user');
    background.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE";
    icon.style.color = "#000000";
}
```

Here is the line `file.html`

```
<span class="icon-case" id="iname"><i class="fa fa-user" id="user"></i></span>
<input type="text" onfocus="chbgn('#3684FF');" onblur="blur();" id="name" name="name" placeholder="FULL NAME" style="width: 37%; margin-right: 50px;">
```

It obviously works for setting the color but unsetting it is a mystery. I am new to working with websites and Javascript in general. Please help.

Comment: just change your ``onblur`` function name. ``blur()`` to ``inpblur()``

Comment: is blur() reserved or something?

Comment: Thank you by the way, it works!